# use F to update with where in Python

Tags: jquery, python, django, sql-update

Hi i have a query in which i need to update the database by matching two values for that i use the below code

```
for i in getDailyGame :
    query2 = "UPDATE  Game_mygame SET game_played = "+str(set_game_played)+" WHERE home_teamID = "+str(i.home_teamID)+ " AND away_teamID = "+str(i.away_teamID)
    cursor2.execute(query2)
```

there is around 4000 entries to be updated but with this it takes so long time 
can i use F class to update if yes than please suggest how to use this 
some thing like

```
myplayer.objects.update(age=F('age')+0.0192)
```

thanks

Comment: Please escape your SQL before doing anything else. You should do this:

Comment: Wasn't able to fit what I wanted to say in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please escape your SQL before doing anything else. You should do this:

```
query = """
    UPDATE Game_mygame SET game_played = %s
    WHERE home_teamID = %s AND away_teamID = %s
"""
cursor.execute(query, (game_played, home_team_id, away_team_id))
```

This will protect you if someone gets malicious values of game_played or the team ids into your system. The cursor will take care of escaping these values so they're safe to run in MySQL.

To answer the rest of your question: no, F expressions are not sufficiently expressive for what you want to do. Fundamentally they AND the clauses you express in them, whereas what you want is to OR together a bunch of queries:

```
(team_id_1 = a1 and team_id_2 = a2) OR (team_id_1 = b1 and team_id_2 = b2) OR ...
```

You can use Q expressions to express this query:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#django.db.models.Q

The expression above turns into:

```
Q(home_teamID=<a1>, away_teamID=<a2>) | Q(home_teamID=<b1>, home_teamID=<b2>) | ...
```

Be aware that this is one of the costlier MySQL queries, though. The best way is probably to batch updates of 64 or so at a time.